# None of my games are working in Wine

Tags: wine, games

Okay, with the exception of StarCraft I, every game I've installed with with Wine will not run (I've tried C&C 3, Worms Armageddon, and Rome Total War). All the games install fine, but when I try to run them (from the winefile), the screen flickers a bit (like it's trying to close out winefile) and then stops. And when I exit out of the winefile it looks like it has reverted my version of Ubuntu back to 10.08 (I think, the one I currently have is 11.04).

This is driving my crazy, as I cannot get any game (with the exception of StarCraft, and even then, the sound doesn't work) to work. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: wine is not so powerful to run max of game. try playonlinux or Cedega. Cedega is not free

Comment: If I can't get this to work, then I might try one of those. However, would the fact that I have /home on a different partition have anything to do with this?

Comment: /home is not problem. Do you have external graphics card ? try to run any windows application (software) which will test wine.

Comment: No, I don't have an external graphics card. I tried running Rome Total War and this is what came up in the terminal: `fixme:ddraw:DirectDrawEnumerateExA flags 0x00000003 not handled
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadDrawable
  Major opcode of failed request:  128 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  5 (X_GLXMakeCurrent)
  Serial number of failed request:  536
  Current serial number in output stream:  536`

Comment: POL uses WINE, and so does Cedega, with Vanilla Wine you need to tweak it further, if you use POL it uses a Wine version that runs the game you want, i.e. Game A no longer works in 1.3.25 but works on version 1.1.x, so POL downloads a file containing that version.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't have expected Wine would run the game, It's far from being useful to run games, even old ones.

Comment: Okay, I'll download PlayOnLinux. But first I want to be sure that the problem isn't something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of to help you i need some more information:

1. Have you checked AppDB from Wine if these games are running fine ? 
   see: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1308

As you can see it is gold rated so it should work. Also the version who is gold rated is the latest wine (1.3.25).

2. Do you have the latest version of wine?
3. Do you have the same version of the games who are reported to work in appdb ?
4. Do you have your real graphics driver installed (fglrx or nvidia) and not those shitty oss drivers (I mean you just can play with the oss driver, its just reality)
5. Did you follow the instructions on the wine page? (in AppDB) for install and startup etc.... (Howto)
6. How do you start the games ? Please post your commands..
7. Also i would not recommend using some gui to start the games, you cant see the console output with my leads to the clue of some missing dlls....

UPDATE:

8. I forgot to ask: Do you have the games installed in a separate wine prefix for each game ? if not -> you should do...

Thanks

M.

Update 2:

1. Go to: http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu or https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa and get the newest version. They are stable!
2. Put this into an console: "glxinfo | grep vendor" it should put out nvida or ati and NOT mesa
3. The instructions are in the appdb from wine normally on one of the versions. for Armagedon they are here: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=1744 (scroll down a bit)
4. Well this is not the way you should start your games. you cant read any warnings and i'm not sure if it is correctly loaded anyway. The correct (working) way for me is:

cd /path/to/game
WINEPREFIX=/Path/to/Prefix wine Game.exe

For more info about Wineprefix see: http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-faf9617c53607e583f6e6ff70a4ac9522d490faf

Comment: I would just like to note that the "shitty" OSS drivers would actually be better to install while you're initially trying to get it to work. The "real" drivers often far more buggy and those drivers themselves may need to be tweaked.

Comment: The 3D performance of the OSS drivers vs the Propietary ones, just can't be compared. And most errors like the ones the OP is having with Wine are related to Wine's DirectX Implementation.

Comment: 1 - No, I have 1.2.2          2 - Yeah, I have RTW Gold edition (which I think is rated platinum)       3 - I think so, but possibly not, how would I check that?      4 - Where are the instructions      5 - winefile, then I browsed to the game.exe and ran it (I've tried cd to the game's folder in /.wine/... but it would say that the it could not find RomeTW.exe in windows//system32//).    Also, how do you add line breaks?

Comment: Wolf please post another answer and not in the comments, i cant read it there very well...

Comment: Sorry, it won't let me post another answer. But, if you tell me how to add line breaks to a comment, I can edit my comment.

Comment: No, you shouldn't post that as an answer, it doesn't work that way, remember is a Q&A site not a forum, keep it on the comments. And your best shot at this is Using Play on Linux, definitively

Comment: well i dont trust these guis very much i tried the cedga gui and it did make quite a mess... But to be fair, this was 2 years back. It just stick to the console now..

Comment: No, they're probably not installed in different prefixes. How do I install them in different ones? Also, in this: `cd /path/to/game WINEPREFIX=/Path/to/Prefix wine Game.exe` is /Path/to/Prefix supposed to be ~/.wine

Comment: yes it is. To do diffent prefix just change the path. wine will create a new one. so before you install the game do WINEPREFIX=/Path/to/new/Prefix wine SETUP.exe then it will get installed into this prefix

Comment: Okay thanks (does this mean I need to re-install the games?). Note: I'm not currently on high-speed, so I won't be able to download the latest wine version until later, so please check back within a day or two in-case I run into another problem with this. Thanks!

Comment: yeah you have to reinstall.. will do

Comment: Okay, I did everything, re-installed two games (worms and total war), and I tried starting both of them the right way (which was  actually working :) but then it asked for me to put in the cd for the game. However, my cdrom drive is set up and was working up till now (actually it still does as it does notice the disks, just not when I try to run them). Would this somehow be due to the fact that the games are now in different prefixes? Oh, and I tried the console command you showed me (glxinfo | etc.) and it had nvidia there, but vendor was in red... is that normal?

Comment: for some games you need a "fix" for the cd cause wine cant handle the windows cd-protection.

Comment: You mean something like: (http://www.megagames.com/fixes/worms-armageddon-v36290-eng)

Comment: Okay, it wasn't a "fix" that I needed. The problem was that I hadn't done winecfg for all the different wineprefixes (and therefore hadn't setup the cd drive for all of them). So it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly says

```
fixme:ddraw:DirectDrawEnumerateExA flags 0x00000003 not handled
```

I.e. wine's implementation of DirectX can not yet handle a certain combination of flags passed to a routine by the game. Try everything Manuel says, then try installing native (Windows-native, that is) DirectX libs using winetricks.